# Autocomplete for DatagridView ComboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid view which is used to bind values.

I have a ComboBox inside this DatagridView; I want to implement an auto complete property in this ComboBox. It should not only search for the first letter but the whole item...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

- Grabbing the `ComboBox`
- Manipulating its `Items`

Let's assume you have only one `ComboBoxColumn`; then you can grab an instance of the current one like this:

```
ComboBox editCombo = null;   // class level variable


private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    editCombo = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (editCombo != null)
    {
        // here we can set its style..
        editCombo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        editCombo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        // sigh..:
        editCombo.TextChanged -= editCombo_TextChanged;
        editCombo.TextChanged += editCombo_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

Let's assume you have the valid list of values in a `List<string>`

```
List<string>() allChoices = new List<string>();
```

Then we can adapt the `Items` to be shown in the `TextChanged` event:

```
void editCombo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String>  items = allChoices.Select(x=>x)
                                    .Where(x=>x.Contains(editCombo.Text)).ToList();

    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        editCombo.Items.Clear();
        editCombo.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
    }
    editCombo.Select(editCombo.Text.Length, 0);  //clear the selection
}
```

Note that this `x=>x.Contains(editCombo.Text)` searches for items that **contain** the full text entered. I hope that is what you mean; searching for items that are **identical** to the entered text makes no sense, as then you do not need to AutoComplete them anyway..